# Why adding a println makes my code uncompilable

Tags: scala

In this function

```
def updateUser(newValues:User):Future[Option[User]] = {
    println("updating user: "+newValues)
    Future(
    //  println("updating user: "+newValues)//Interestinng. Addinng this makes code uncompilable
    updateOneById(newValues,UserKeys(1,newValues.profile.externalProfileDetails.email))
  )}
```

If I uncomment the above code, I get error `cannot resolve updateOneById`

The above method is defined in the following class

```
class UsersRepository(session: Session,tablename:String) 
  extends CassandraRepository[UserKeys,User](session, tablename, List("bucket","email")) with UserDao {...}
```

and `updateOneById` is defined in `CassandraRepository` as

```
def updateOneById(data:M, id: I): Option[M] = {
    println("updating table "+tablename+" with partition key  "+partitionKeyColumns +" and values "+id)
    val resultSet = session.execute(updateValues(tablename,data, id))

    val it = resultSet.iterator();
    if(it.hasNext)
      Some(data) //TODOM should this be Some(rowToModel(it.next()))?
    else
      None
  }
```

However, if I use `{` in place of `(` in the `Future` then the code compiles.

```
def updateUser(newValues:User):Future[Option[User]] = {
    println("updating user: "+newValues)
    Future {
      println("updating user: "+newValues)//using { in place of ( works
      updateOneById(newValues, UserKeys(1, newValues.profile.externalProfileDetails.email))
    }}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use parentheses the compiler expects an expression inside the parantheses and not a block of code. With the `println(...)` added the compiler tries to make the contents of the parantheses into one expression by invoking the `updateOneById` method on the return value of the `println` statement. But this is of type Unit and doesn't have that method.

If you replace the parentheses by curly braces the compiler expects a block of code and can separate the 2 lines into 2 statements. 
You might get an error message that is a bit clearer if you put a semicolon after the println to indicate to the compiler that these are 2 statements.